# grunt-watch when you create a new folder does not work

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

`grunt-watch` is being created using the program. A new added folder will not be found when it's added to the `js` directory.

If the file structure looks like the following:

```
  js/moduleA.js
  js/moduleB.js
  js/modules/moduleC.js
```

And glob pattern `"**/*.js"` if `moduleB.js` or `moduleA.js` or `modules/moduleC.js` module changes, it works fine.

However, `grunt-watch` running `js` folder under a new folder for the new folder is added, it does not recognize the watch.

```
   // Grunt watch running ....
   // create new_folder and create moduleD.js
   js/new_modules/moduleD.js <------ Even if it changes the watch does not work.
```

Is the glob pattern wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue: [New subfolders aren't watched until watch task is restarted](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/70)